# getifaddrs to parse only the IP from etherenet interface (eth) or wlan interface

Tags: linux, ip-address, ipconfig

I have used the program which is present in the following link  http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/3/getifaddrs.htm .

but it prints all the IP like loopback,eth0,eth1 lo etc

now I need to get only the ip which are active excpet loopback ip 
ex

$iffconfig
    eth6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:47:99:da
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe47:99da/64 Scope:Link
   as the ifconfig gives the active interface and correspoding IPs

what has to be changed in this code to get the above thing working ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
    if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL)
        continue;

    family = ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family;
```

with

```
    if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL)
        continue;

    if ((strcmp("lo", ifa->ifa_name) == 0) ||
        !(ifa->ifa_flags & (IFF_RUNNING)))
        continue;

    family = ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family;
```

and add this line just after the other includes

```
#include <net/if.h>
```

The added lines just check for "lo" interface name, contained into `ifa->ifa_name`, and check the flags of the interfaces. Testing IFF_RUNNING bit ( look at `net/if.h` for further definitions) will return only running interfaces.

If you want to check other feature of the interfaces, just check for this flags (taken from `net/if.h`)

- IFF_UP   Interface is running.
- IFF_BROADCAST    Valid broadcast address set.
- IFF_DEBUG    Internal debugging flag.
- IFF_LOOPBACK Interface is a loopback interface.
- IFF_POINTOPOINT  Interface is a point-to-point link.
- IFF_RUNNING  Resources allocated.
- IFF_NOARP     No arp protocol, L2 destination address not set.
- IFF_PROMISC  Interface is in promiscuous mode.
- IFF_NOTRAILERS   Avoid use of trailers.
- IFF_ALLMULTI Receive all multicast packets.
- IFF_MASTER   Master of a load balancing bundle.
- IFF_SLAVE    Slave of a load balancing bundle.
- IFF_MULTICAST    Supports multicast
- IFF_PORTSEL  Is able to select media type via ifmap.
- IFF_AUTOMEDIA    Auto media selection active.
- IFF_DYNAMIC   The addresses are lost when the interface goes down.
- IFF_LOWER_UP Driver signals L1 up (since Linux 2.6.17)
- IFF_DORMANT  Driver signals dormant (since Linux 2.6.17)
- IFF_ECHO Echo sent packets (since Linux 2.6.25)

**EDIT**

if you need to discriminate IPV6 GUA and ULA address use this macros

```
#ifndef IN6_IS_ADDR_GLOBAL
#define IN6_IS_ADDR_GLOBAL(a) \
        ((((__const uint32_t *) (a))[0] & htonl(0x70000000)) \
        == htonl (0x20000000))
#endif /* IS ADDR GLOBAL */

#ifndef IN6_IS_ADDR_ULA
#define IN6_IS_ADDR_ULA(a) \
        ((((__const uint32_t *) (a))[0] & htonl(0xfe000000)) \
        == htonl (0xfc000000))
#endif /* IS ADDR ULA */
```

the parameter must be taken from `((sockaddr_in6 *)ifa->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr;`

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the information the above code helped to get ipv4/v6 ..  Now I need to get only the  ULA if the host has ULA, GUA and link local addressing  IPV6 address ,,  is there any separate flag to verify this ..?

Comment: Can I use the same in virtual environment? How can I set interface down in virtual environment? I am running test program which checks IFF_RUNNING flag at every 500 milliseconds. I am not receiving interface down, it always finds IFF_RUNNING flag set. Need help in this matter.